# Python, Is there a way to find the properties of a subregion within a larger image region?

Tags: python, image, scikit-image

The goal: I have images with particles that I need to find the area of. (`(array([], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int64)), <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (512, 512, 3) <class 'tuple'>`)Each particle also has four to five sub-regions that I need to know the area of. Think of a bunch of stripped shirts in a picture. I need to find the area of each shirt and for a certain shirt, I need to know the area of each stripe. The problem is I need to know which shirt the stripes go to. I need to know what particle the smaller regions correspond to. This is so I can get the percent area of each sub-region in a region.
I have an image of just the large particles in a grey scale, an image of all the overlay sub-regions and an image of each sub region separately. I have created a simplified mock-up of the images. [SubRegion1][1] [SubRegion2][2] [TotalAreaRegion][3]

What I have tried:
Using openCV to do segmentation and then regionprops from scikit-image.org I can get the major particle size, aspect ratio, ect.
What I cannot do is get these sub-regions area and know which parent particle they go to. I produce two separate lists of labels when I want one.

Code:

```py
#markers are the marked regions in the total image. red_markers are the marked sub-regions in the second image.
       markers = cv2.watershed(crop_img, markers)
       red_markers = cv2.watershed(red_crop_img, red_markers)


    #if marker = 1, bg, then color 
    crop_img[markers == 1] = [0, 255, 255]
     red_crop_img[red_markers == 1] = [0, 255, 255]
     img2 = color.label2rgb(markers, bg_label=0)
     red_img2 = color.label2rgb(red_markers, bg_label=0)
    mask = red_markers == 255
    masked_img = markers[mask] = 255
    img3 = np.unique(masked_img, return_counts=True)
     print(img3)
output: array[0]array[255]

'''


 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVef6.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhqDZ.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZWJC.png
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please share your approach.

Comment: Hi, updated the post with the code I am using, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the problem but if I've understood correctly the following should work:

1. Label the particles in the large particle grey scale image (`skimage.morphology.label`)
2. Mask the image using one of the sub-region masks (you could just use numpy indexing for this e.g. `label_image[mask]`)
3. See which labels remain, these labels identify the particles that overlap with the mask (`np.unique(label_image[mask])`)
4. Repeat for the remaining sub-regions

You could measure the areas like `np.unique(label_image, return_counts=True)`. This will return an array of labels and an array of the number of pixels with that label. Similarly, for just pixels in a given sub-region defined by mask, you can measure the areas like `np.unique(label_image[mask], return_counts=True)`.

Here's a MWE demonstrating this approach

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.morphology

### Create example images

full_image = np.array(
    [[ 255, 255, 255,   0,   0],
     [ 255, 255, 255,   0,   0],
     [   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
     [   0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
     [ 255, 255,   0, 255, 255]],
    dtype='uint8')

subregion_image = np.array(
    [[255,   0, 255,   0,   0],
     [255,   0, 255,   0,   0],
     [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
     [  0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
     [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0]],
    dtype='uint8')

# Make format match that format (i.e. RGB) and datatype of OP
full_image = np.repeat(full_image[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2).astype(dtype='int32')
subregion_image = np.repeat(subregion_image[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2).astype(dtype='int64')

### Simplify images

# If we know all three channels are the same it's easier (and equivalent) to have a single channel
full_image = full_image[:, :, 0]  
subregion_image = subregion_image[:, :, 0]

# If we know values are all in the range 0 to 255 we may as well use uint8, miage not matter but it's
# generally helps avoid confusion when dealing with images to have intensity range and datatype match
full_image = full_image.astype('uint8')
subregion_image = subregion_image.astype('uint8')

### Solve the problem

# Label the particles in the large particle image
label_image = skimage.morphology.label(full_image)

# Create a mask for the sub-region
mask = subregion_image == 255

# See which labels remain, these labels identify the particles that overlap with the mask
print(np.unique(label_image[mask]))

# To measure the area we'll set pixels outside the subregion to 0 for background
label_image[~mask] = 0

# Count pixels belonging to each particle
particle_label, pixel_count = np.unique(label_image, return_counts=True)
print(particle_label)
print(pixel_count)
```

If you've got a PIL image or similar you'll probably need to convert to numpy arrays like `your_image = np.array(your_image)`.

Since you'll be looping over the sub-regions this approach might not be particularly fast if you've got millions of sub-regions.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this method out. Is this explanation better?  Think of a bunch of stripped shirts in a picture. I need to find the area of each shirt and for a certain shirt, I need to know the area of each stripe. The problem is I need to know which shirt the stripes go to. I need to know what particle the smaller regions correspond to. This is so I can get the percent area of each sub-region in a region.

Comment: I attempted this approach (full code appended above). I got two arrays of 255 and 1. I am fairly new at this. Can you help me figure out where my misunderstanding is? Thank you for you time!  mask = red_markers == 255 
 masked_img = markers[mask] = 255
img3 = np.unique(masked_img, return_counts=True)
 print(img3).

Comment: Could you edit your code to be a minimal example? Most of your current code doesn't relate to the question and it would take me a while to understand. Start with the images after all your segmentation is complete.

Ideally you'd provide a MWE which I could copy and run myself but that can be tricky for images. At least describe the images: give their data type (uint8? boolean?), shape (e.g. (128, 128, 3) and what the values represent (e.g. 0 is background, 1 is foreground).

Then give the code you've tried and any output (if it's crazy long maybe just the top and bottom).

Comment: If I've understood correctly there are two input images - the full image and a sub region image (once you've got it to work on one sub region I'm sure you can figure out how to loop through the remaining ones).

Comment: That is correct, there are two images. If I can get two to work then, yes, I am sure I can loop through the rest of the sub region images. Here is the data type for the images: (array([], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int64)). Size:
(512, 512, 3). Foreground =255, background =0. They are png files. I corrected the code to only show the part where I try to mask the full image with the sub regions. Please let me know if I can further clarify the question. I don't know what information might be important to solve this problem.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a working example of my solution, give it a try. If it doesn't work try updating the first section ('Create example images') to match your data and put that in your question.